# execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

iam trying to insert the data from dataloader getting error as nullpointerexception in line29 column1.

```
trigger emailmatchdatacontact on ContactRelationship__c (before insert,before update) 
{
    List<ContactRelationship__c> con= new List<ContactRelationship__c>();
    List<Contact> conlist=new List<Contact>();
    Set<String> valtocheck=new Set<String>();
    Map<String,Contact> valfound=new Map<String,Contact>();
    for(ContactRelationship__c cr:trigger.new)
    {
      if(!string.isBlank(cr.EmailId__c)) valToCheck.add(cr.EmailId__c);

    }
    system.debug(valToCheck);
    Map<String, boolean> contactRelationCheckMap = new Map<String, boolean>();
    if(valtocheck != null)
    {
    List<Contact> conrelList = new List<Contact>();
    conrelList = [select id,Email from Contact where Email IN:valtocheck];
    if(conrelList.size()>0)
    { 
    for(Contact c:conrelList)
    {   
        contactRelationCheckMap.put(c.Email, true);
    }
        for(ContactRelationship__c cr:trigger.new) 
        {  
            System.debug('null condition value' + cr.EmailId__c);
            for(Contact c:conrelList)
            {
            if(cr.EmailId__c !=null && contactRelationCheckMap.get(cr.EmailId__c))
            {   
                contact connn=new contact();
                connn.Opt_out_status__c=true; 
                connn.opt_out_transaction__c=system.today();
                connn.id=c.Id;
                conlist.add(connn);
                system.debug(c);
                system.debug(connn);
                system.debug('data available');
                system.debug(contactRelationCheckMap);
                } 

            }
        }
         system.debug('conlistconlistconlistconlist');
         system.debug(conlist);
        // valfound.put(cr.Email,cr);
    } 
     // update conlist;
      //System.debug(conlist);

    }

    try
   {
    system.debug('data available');
    system.debug(conlist);
    update conlist;
    }
    catch(system.NullPointerException e)
    {
        system.debug('data not available');
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which line is 29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to `contactRelationCheckMap` not contains the key you are using to get values. Add a `containskey()` check before getting values from map.

Update your if condition to:

```
if(cr.EmailId__c !=null && contactRelationCheckMap.containsKey(cr.EmailId__c) && contactRelationCheckMap.get(cr.EmailId__c))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are querying records here at line `conrelList = [select id,Email from Contact where Email IN:valtocheck];` trigger runs before and after insert, this query will get newly inserted records `after insert` but in case of before insert if `valtocheck` contains any value that do not have any contact before then `contactRelationCheckMap` will not contain any value for it. So may be you can use contains() method or split logic for before insert and after insert.